# Erro ao usar DELETE com INNER JOIN no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

```
DELETE tbl_grupo_id FROM gc_art_test.tbl_grupo_tbl_permission
INNER JOIN gc_art_test.tbl_grupos
ON tbl_grupo_tbl_permission.tbl_grupo_id = tbl_grupos.id
WHERE tbl_grupo_tbl_permission.tbl_grupo_id = 2246
```

**Erro Apresentado:**

*Erro SQL (1109): Unknown table 'tbl_grupo_id' in MULTI DELETE*

Comment: precisa dar alias corretos para as tabelas, por exemplo `DELETE p FROM gc_art_test.tbl_grupo_tbl_permission AS p` e assim por diante

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, era isso... Eu ate tinha colocado mas errei na sintaxe..... Obrigado